# Need help configuring new user signup email notification

Tags: 6, emails, users

I am new to Drupal and use Drupal 6 now. I have a site all built up and I want to just send a *new member* email template when he sign-ups. I don't want any other email templates for now.

I installed postFix on the server. I also use [FB for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/fb) module.

My Question is this: How do I send welcome email?

Please let me know steps, modules I need (if basic modules are not enough) etc.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow for registering users can be configured at `index.php?q=admin/user/settings`. If this does not suit your needs, let us know how your workflow differs from what can be configured on that page.

I suspect you want to check the option **Visitors can create accounts and no administrator approval is required.** and uncheck the option **Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account**. The e-mail that are sent can be configured in the fieldset **User e-mail settings** and for some e-mails, you can configure whether to send them at all.

Comment: Ok, now say I want to send an email template when a custom event occurs, such as on a site with reviews on other sites, send email when new review is added. How do I do that?

Comment: Use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.